# Nameserver problem

Tags: domains, dns, vps, nameserver

I recently bought a new VPS, and I was trying to set private nameservers in my domain cPanel.

I went ahead and added 4 A records:

- ns1.mydomain.com - points to my IP
- ns2.mydomain.com - points to my IP
- www.mydomain.com - points to my IP
- mydomain.com - points to my IP

and changed the nameservers to ns1 and ns2.mydomain.com. The problem is that now
while typing www.ns1.mydomain.com and www.ns2.mydomain.com in the browser, it points to the correct IP address, but the www.mydomain.com domain is returning an error:

```
The webpage at http://mydomain.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

The error message above was received in Chrome.

Comment: It would help if we know what `mydomain.com` actually is, so we can check your DNS records remotely. Also, how long have you waited for the DNS changes to propagate? It can take up to 72 hours to work properly.

Comment: @Oldskool , www.demiracles.com

Comment: @Oldskool , Here is my Domain Panel Screen Shots , http://i47.tinypic.com/2i9pf2f.jpg  AND  http://i45.tinypic.com/34dpy0x.jpg

Comment: Wild guess... have you changed the correct/master DNS zone? Nothing else resolves apart from the `ns1` and `ns2` sub domains (as you say).

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you run your domain through intodns.com?  That can help you spot errors in your setup.

A common mistake is including or not including a dot on the left hand side of the entries in zone setup.

Consider this entry with a dot

[image]

This creates a record "testing" pointing to the specified IP address.  Probably not not what you want.

Consider this entry with out a dot:

[image]

In this case, if your domain was "domain.com", the resulting A record would be:
testing.domain.com pointing to the specified IP address.

Comment: my domain name is www.demiracles.com

Comment: Here is my Domain Panel Screen Shots , http://i47.tinypic.com/2i9pf2f.jpg  AND  http://i45.tinypic.com/34dpy0x.jpg